# Opencart 2.2 : Redirect user to same page after login

Tags: php, opencart2.x

In Opencart, I am unable to do that after login the user go to the previous page on which the user is, rather than the account page. I am not interested to use any extension for it.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass current URL along with your login form 
your current URL will be like this :

```
<?php 
   $url = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
?>
```

pass it in a hidden field of a form ,

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" >
```

After successful login redirect to this URL

```
$this->response->redirect($_POST['redirect']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Open catalog/controller/account/login.php file

find for this

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {  
$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
}
```

replace it by

```
 if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {  
$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
}elseif(!isset($this->session->data['redirect']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
$this->session->data['redirect'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

Hope the answer for the question